# Wit.ai PHP cURL execute bot function?

Tags: php, curl, bots

It is my first time working with bots. I decided to use wit.ai bot, using PHP. What I am trying to do is to set callback function for the bot, for example when user ask for weather the bot will execute `getWeather()`. How can I pass this function to the bot if I am using `cURL`? Is it possible to do that? I found some SDKs on git but all of them are unofficial for wit.ai.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$headr = array();
$headr[] = "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.wit.ai/message?v=20170118&q=what is weather in London ?");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

echo $server_output;
```

i've found this SDK https://github.com/tgallice/wit-php, but i am not able to use ActionMapping its always given error :

> Fatal error: Class 'ActionMapping' not found in
>   /Users/jack/Documents/www/bar/index.php on line 12

**my code :**

```
   <?php
    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

    use Tgallice\Wit\Client;
    use Tgallice\Wit\ConverseApi;
    use Tgallice\Wit\Conversation;

    use Tgallice\Wit\Model\Step\Action;
    use Tgallice\Wit\Model\Step\Message;

    class MyActionMapping extends ActionMapping
    {
        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function action($sessionId, Context $context, Action $step)
        {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, $step->getAction()), array($sessionId, $context));
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function say($sessionId, Context $context, Message $step)
        {
            echo $step->getMessage();
        }

    }

    $client = new Client('XXX');
    $api = new ConverseApi($client);
    $actionMapping = new MyActionMapping();
    $conversation = new Conversation($api, $actionMapping);

$context = $conversation->converse('session_id', 'Hello I live in London');
```

Comment: There is no `POST /message` endpoint. Please be more specific and ask a reproducible, clear problem or simply read the docs... https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526#get--message-link

Comment: @DanFromGermany , sorry i am new for this , i saw the link you've provided its not clear enough !!

Comment: The `ActionMapping` class is namespaced.  Your class needs to properly extend it with `class MyActionMapping extends \Tgallice\Wit\ActionMapping` or add `use Tgallice\Wit\ActionMapping` at the top of your class file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783433/wit-ai-php-sdk-uncaught-error-actionmapping and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803815/php-wit-php-unable-to-use-custom-actionmapping

Answer (score 4):

According to your error, are you sure about these things:

> Install library:

First of all, install library via composer so that all files should add correctly. Maybe it will be the main cause.

> Parameter passed in curl:

For wheater, you have used https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526 API. Also here token part is missing form curl

and hit this function :

```
$ curl -XPOST 'https://api.wit.ai/converse?v=20160526&session_id=123abc&q=weather%20in%20Brussels' \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      -H "Accept: application/json" \
      -H 'Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN'
Response:

  {
    "type": "merge",
    "entities": {"location": [{"body": "Brussels",
                               "value": {"type": "value",
                                         "value": "Brussels",
                                         "suggested": true},
                               "start": 11,
                               "end": 19,
                               "entity": "location"}]},
    "confidence": 1
  }
```